# Error inInstalling ldap on ubuntu 16.04 with php7.0, E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: ldap, ubuntu-16.04, php-7

I got this error while i write this command Please help

root@mukul-HP-15-Notebook-PC:/var/lib/dpkg# apt-get install php7.0-ldap
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
php7.0-ldap is already the newest version (7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 217 not upgraded.
15 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up php7.0-common (7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing package php7.0-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-json:
 php7.0-json depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-json (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-opcache:
 php7.0-opcache depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-opcache (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-readline:
 php7.0-readline depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-readline (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-cli:
 php7.0-cli depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.13-0ubuNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
            No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                                      No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                   No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                 ntu0.16.04.1); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.
 php7.0-cli depends on php7.0-json; however:
  Package php7.0-json is not configured yet.
 php7.0-cli depends on php7.0-opcache; however:
  Package php7.0-opcache is not configured yet.
 php7.0-cli depends on php7.0-readline; however:
  Package php7.0-readline is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-cli (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libapache2-mod-php7.0:
 libapache2-mod-php7.0 depends on php7.0-cli; however:
  Package php7.0-cli is not configured yet.
 libapache2-mod-php7.0 depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.
 libapache2-mod-php7.0 depends on php7.0-json; however:
  Package php7.0-json is not configured yet.
 libapache2-mod-php7.0 depends on php7.0-opcache; however:
  Package php7.0-opcache is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                             libapache2-mod-php7.0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-ldap:
 php7.0-ldap depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-ldap (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php-ldap:
 php-ldap depends on php7.0-ldap; however:
  Package php7.0-ldap is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                            dpkg: error processing package php-ldap (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0:
 php7.0 depends on php7.0-fpm | libapache2-mod-php7.0 | php7.0-cgi; however:
  Package php7.0-fpm is not installed.
  Package libapache2-mod-php7.0 is not configured yet.
  Package php7.0-cgi is not installed.
 php7.0 depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-curl:
 php7.0-curl depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-curl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-gd:
 php7.0-gd depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-gd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-mbstring:
 php7.0-mbstring depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-mbstring (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-mcrypt:
 php7.0-mcrypt depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-mcrypt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-mysql:
 php7.0-mysql depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-mysql (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-xml:
 php7.0-xml depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-xml (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 php7.0-common
 php7.0-json
 php7.0-opcache
 php7.0-readline
 php7.0-cli
 libapache2-mod-php7.0
 php7.0-ldap
 php-ldap
 php7.0
 php7.0-curl
 php7.0-gd
 php7.0-mbstring
 php7.0-mcrypt
 php7.0-mysql
 php7.0-xml
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the dependencies first manually or you can do apt-get install -f to automatically install them.

Comment: NOT Working, still same problem

Comment: In my case problem was internet speed